# How do you print out NULL from ruby to javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

If you have javascript being written in HAML, with a ruby array being interpolated into javascript, how do you get ruby to print out NULL?

```
:javascript
  $().ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("table#hands-table").dataTable( {
        "aoColumns" : #{@column_sort_types},
```

If @column_sort_types contains an empty space or nil, neither will print out NULL.  And trying to add NULL to a ruby array creates a ruby error.  Do I have to perform a javascript regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:javascript
  $().ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("table#hands-table").dataTable( {
        "aoColumns" : #{@column_sort_types.present? ? @column_sort_types : "NULL"},
```

This uses `Object#present?` which is the opposite of `blank?`. These are additions to `Object` by ActiveSupport. Objects are blank, if they are either empty or one of nil, false, or a string of only white space.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
#{@column_sort_types.to_json}
```

The to_json will work on nil:

```
nil.to_json
 => "null"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I properly understand what do you mean, you can use ruby's 'open class' ability:

```
class Array
   def to_array_with_null
     self.map do |val|
       val = "NULL" if val.nil? or (val.respond_to? :empty? and val.empty?)
       val
     end
  end
end

[1, '2', 3, nil, ''].to_array_with_null  # => [1, "2", 3, "NULL", "NULL"]
```

And you can use `#{@column_sort_types.to_array_with_null}` instead of `#{@column_sort_types}` in such case. Correct me if I understand you wrong.

Answer (score 1):

just pass nil to javascript, the javascript would treat it as variable with name "nil", then define the variable `var nil = null` in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

%Q seems to be the element I was missing.

```
%Q[null, null]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "NULL" in Ruby on Rails will print "NULL" (with quotes) in javascript. But javascript needs null without quotes. I still could not figure this one out.